# Send different attachment to different recipient in appointment EWS (Exchange Web Service)

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to send meeting invitation by Appointment class of EWS.
I have a requirement to send different attachment to different recipients. I am referencing the following links:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/cf4b9d9a-7bbb-4caa-9d55-300371fa84ac/ews-attachment-not-sent-with-invitation

This link is just for one or more than one attachment might to be sent but I need each recipients should have different-2 attachments.

I am trying to following in my code that might be helpful to better understand the challenge:

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service) {
  Start = DateTime.Now,
    End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
    Subject = "XYZ Invitation",
    Location = "XYZ Tower, Room No. 3",
    IsAllDayEvent = false,
    AllowNewTimeProposal = false,
    IsResponseRequested = false,
    Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, html),
    ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60

};

int i = 0;
foreach(var attendee in attendies) { // List<string> 
  appointment.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(Image[i], file);
  appointment.Attachments[0].IsInline = true;
  appointment.Attachments[0].ContentId = Image[i];

  FolderId folderCalendar = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, attendee);
  appointment.Save(folderCalendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);

  appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(attendee);
  i++;

  appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use **Bind** method of **Appointment** class in order to send different attachment second time to add receipt.

```
appointment.Bind(ExchangeService, ItemId, PropertySet);
```

Binds to an existing appointment and loads the specified set of properties. Calling this method results in a call to Exchange Web Services (EWS).

I hope it helps you.

Comment: It will look into its documentation. Can you provide me any example please ?

Comment: Look into this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment_methods(v=exchg.80).aspx